# Hive: Left outer join with rlike condition

Tags: hive

As we know theta joins (non equality joins) are not supported by hive.

In a normal join I would have handled it something like:

```
Select t.A, t.B, u.D
from table t
join uTable u
where t.C rlike u.C
```

Now, I want to do a left join. Putting rlike in where condition will filter out non matches and result wont have null values keys.
How to handle this scenario in hive?

During playing around I found this approach. Is this a right start?

```
Select t.A, t.B, u.D
from table t
left outer join uTable u
where ( t.C rlike u.C
or t.C rlike '' )
```